# Scalable Journeys in Marketing cloud with different templates

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

Is there any scalable way of designing a journey in Marketing Cloud which:

1. Sends a different email (the template) depending on the current data data? i.e. a contact picklist value with 25 possible values.
2. Let's us choose the a different sender profile for each different template.

So far, **the only solution I have come up with is to create a different journey for each subset of data**... the problem is that each time we add a new possible value to the contact with its corresponding templates and sender profile, we have to create a new journey for it.

Furthermore, **I have also thought of creating a massive email template with AMPScript which multiplexes** different blocks as well as the sender profile depending on the variable value... but AMPScript can get messy easy and fast imo.

So, all in all, I was wondering if you know of any other way to face this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the complexity of the email you can use dynamic content to display the entire email based on a variable.

To your point, ampscript is another option as well.

Finally, you could do decision splits based off the variable within a journey.

For sender profile ampscript is likely your easiest option. (If a certain set of variables gives a given output of ID you could create a mapping in a separate DE and use a look up function) You could also just have the email address as a field within your DE and reference using ampscript directly.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a data extension with different values of the pick-list. With that different values you can make decision inside the journey with these templates.
Versioning in marketing cloud is a tough matter, in many cases you won't have any other chance of updating your data.

Answer (score 0):

You do t need different journeys, instead have one journey which will have a decision split based on picmlust values and choose your required email template and send classification for the respective email sends.

This will help you to avoid ampscript for content and we sender profile. However it will increase maintenance for Journey( adding new picmlust value and corresponding decision path) and email templates ( common change across all email templates).

Answer (score 0):

If the email templates are similar and the difference is mainly in content you can create an enhanced dynamic block in the email and upload a file with the pick list values and the corresponding content so at the time of email send the email picks up the content dynamically. 
Thanks.